# how to stagger equations by aligning to specific terms in sequence of characters?

Tags: equations, align

I need to stagger a system of difference equations so that incremented indices on proceeding lines appear underneath their corresponding index on the line above them. This has proven challenging because the indexed terms appear in a sequence of characters, which causes LaTeX to split elements that should be one term when & or && is applied between them.

Shown below are the first three equations, easily aligned at the equals sign. However, I also want to align functions 'u' whose indices match, i.e., 'u_{1,j}', 'u_{2,j}', etc., on the RHS.

Typing '\nonumber' is also a pain, makes no sense that this environment doesn't use * to suspend numbering. Is '{alignat*}{n} identical to '{align}' in every other sense? does 'n' stand for the number of equations or the number of alignment points? (please ignore this paragraph if '{alignat*}' isn't the solution to my problem anyway.

Also,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{amsthm} 
\usepackage[]{amssymb} 
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{physics}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbered]{matlab-prettifier}


\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{u_{1,j+1}} &= 0 + \left(1-2\boldsymbol{r}\right)\boldsymbol{u_{1,j}} + \boldsymbol{r u_{2,j}}\nonumber\\
\boldsymbol{u_{2,j+1}} &= \boldsymbol{r}\boldsymbol{u_{1,j}} + \left(1-2\boldsymbol{r}\right)\boldsymbol{u_{2,j}} + \boldsymbol{r u_{3,j}}\nonumber\\
\boldsymbol{u_{3,j+1}} &= \boldsymbol{r}\boldsymbol{u_{2,j}} + \left(1-2\boldsymbol{r}\right)\boldsymbol{u_{3,j}} + \boldsymbol{r u_{4,j}}\nonumber\\
\nonumber\end{align}
```

Result should look similar to

[image]

All help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

with `alignat*`; instead of `amsmath` i use `mathtools` (for `\shortintertext`) and for bold face math font i suggest to use package `\bm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{5}
\bm{u}_{1,j+1}
    & = 0 + (1-2 & \bm{r}) & \bm{u}_{1,j} + \bm{r u}_{2,j} &&    \\
\bm{u}_{2,j+1}
    & =          & \bm{r}~ & \bm{u}_{1,j} + (1-2
                        & \bm{r})& \bm{u}_{2,j} + \bm{r u}_{3,j}
\shortintertext{\hspace{8em}\dotfill\hspace*{3.5em}}
\bm{u}_{3,j+1}
    & = &  &            & \bm{r}~ & \bm{u}_{2,j} + (1-2\bm{r})\bm{u}_{3,j} + \bm{r u}_{4,j}
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: interesting, except that the dots are "running away".  you might want to put a matching `\hspace` (plus something for a "stopper", either `\kern0pt` or a strut) at the ribht-hand end of the intertext.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, done. very rudimentary :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is easy with `alignat*` (note the starred version ads no number). This makes $5$ alignment points, hence it requires  9 ampersands. I removed all unnecessary packages for the problem at hand, and  moved the language option of babel to the document cleass, as should be since version 3.10:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{5}
\boldsymbol{u_{1,j+1}} &={}&0 +(1-2\boldsymbol{r})\boldsymbol{u_{1,j}} & &{}+ \boldsymbol{r u_{2,j}} &\\
\boldsymbol{u_{2,j+1}} &= & \boldsymbol{r}\boldsymbol{u_{1,j}} & &{} + (1-2\boldsymbol{r})\boldsymbol{u_{2,j}} & &{}+ \boldsymbol{r u_{3,j}} & \\
\boldsymbol{u_{3,j+1}} &= & & & \boldsymbol{r}\boldsymbol{u_{2,j}} & &{}+(1-2\boldsymbol{r})\boldsymbol{u_{3,j}} & & {}+ \boldsymbol{r u_{4,j}} &
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A vertically spaced out `array` should suffice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{r >{{}}c<{{}} r<{{}} >{{}}c<{{}} r >{{}}c<{{}} ll}
u_{1,j+1}   & = & 0+(1-2r)u_{1,j} & + & ru_{2,j} \\
u_{2,j+1}   & = &        ru_{1,j} & + & (1-2r)u_{2,j} & + & ru_{3,j} \\
& \multicolumn{7}{c}{\;\dotfill\hphantom{{}+0}} \\
u_{N-1,j+1} & = & &&&&& ru_{N-2,j}+(1-2r)u_{N-1,j}+0
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]